# Nodejs - how can I save a file object sent from frontend to the public folder without using middleware like multer?

Tags: node.js, multer

I have a React client side app and a Nodejs backend.

I am trying to sent a stringified json and some pdf files (uploaded from the client side by [react-dropzone](https://github.com/react-dropzone/react-dropzone)) as formdata/multipart in a put request like this:

```
let formData = new FormData()

formData.append('user', JSON.stringify(jsonData))
formData.append('file_1', user.file_1)
formData.append('file_2', user.file_2)
```

In my Nodejs backend, I extract the form data with multer:

```
let multerInstance = multer();
userRouter.put('/user/:user_id', validateJwt, multerInstance.any(), putUser);
```

and I extract the formdata like this:

```
const formData = req.body;
const user = JSON.parse(formData.user);
const files = req.files; // here I have file_1 and file_2 as file objects
```

however, if I use multer to save the files, I have to pass the config settings in the middleware like this:

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, './public/uploads');
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    var fileFormat = file.originalname.split('.');
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + '.' + fileFormat[fileFormat.length - 1]);
  },
});

let multerInstance = multer({
  storage: storage,
});

let multerInstance = multer();
userRouter.put('/user/:user_id', validateJwt, multerInstance.any(), putUser);
```

which I don't want to, **because I want to decide whether to do the upload action (save to /public/uploads) inside putUser, instead of setting the destination in the multer middleware (which will run before putUser, no matter what)**

how can I achieve this?

Comment: You can configure multer and only call it from inside of `putUser()` when you are ready.  If you supply your own `next()` function instead of the standard one, it will call your function when it's done rather than the next route.  You need software to read the body and parse the multipart mime and it's not fun to write that yourself which is why I recommend you use existing software for the parsing.

Comment: @jfriend00 Would you mind providing an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Glad to figured out the solution using `fs.writeFile`

First, use multer on the route like this without any configuration so that it only works as a formdata phaser:

```
let multerInstance = multer();
userRouter.put('/user/:user_id', validateJwt, multerInstance.any(), putUser);
```

Next, obtain the files with `req.files` in the route, files that phased by `multer` will look like this:

```
{
    fieldname: 'myField',
    originalname: 'file_1.pdf',
    encoding: '7bit',
    mimetype: 'application/pdf',
    buffer: <Buffer 25 50 44 46 2d 31 2e 33 0a 25 c4 e5 f2 e5 eb a7 f3 a0 d0 c4 c6 0a 34 20 30 20 6f 62 6a 0a 3c 3c 20 2f 4c 65 6e 67 74 68 20 35 20 30 20 52 20 2f 46 69 ... 51728 more bytes>,
    size: 51778
}
```

Since I observe that there's a buffer in the file, I can write the file to the target path using the `fs` module so that the upload action can be done inside the route.

```
const files = req.files

const uploadFiles = files.map((file) => {
   return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
       let fileFormat = file.originalname.split('.');
       let savePath = file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + '.' + fileFormat[fileFormat.length - 1];
       fs.writeFile('./public/uploads/' + savePath, file.buffer, function (err) {
         if (err) {
            return reject();
         }

         return resolve();
      });
   });
});

await Promise.all(uploadFiles);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can configure multer and only call it from inside of `putUser()` when you are ready. If you supply your own `next()` function to the middleware instead of the standard one, it will call your function when it's done rather than the next route.

You need software to read the body and parse the multipart mime and it's not fun to write that yourself which is why I recommend you use existing software for the parsing.

Here's a general idea for how that could look:

```
function putUser(req, res, next) {
    // do a bunch of your own logic here
    if (iWantToProcessFile) {
        // call multer middleware to process form data
        let multerFn = multerInstance.any();
        multerFn(req, res, function(err) {
            if (err) return next(err);
            // use multer data on req object now to finish your request
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: But in that case how can I phase the `formdata`? I want to check whether the user data i.e. `JSON.parse(formData.user)` is correct before performing the upload, without the multer middleware outside, I can't even get the user data from req.body

Comment: @Andus - Well, I can't help you further without a full example of what you're trying to do.  As you requested, I showed an answer for my suggestion based on the little you've actually described of the problem.  If `.user` is inside the formData, then you have to process the form data before you can see it.  At this point, I don't know what else to suggest given how little you've shown of the actual problem.  This level of conceptual answer is the best that can be offered with what we have so far.

Comment: @Andus - Usually a user would be authenticated separately, long before uploading a file and that auth information would be in a cookie which is available before processing the upload data.

Comment: Thanks for you help and your answer gives me some inspiration. I'm actually trying to confirm the user_id inside the user data is indeed the one who send the request. The user is already authenticated in the validateJwt middleware, but im trying to make one more step further

Comment: I am looking for any alternatives like that I can call the "save" part when I was ready instead of calling at the time the formdata is being phased. e.g. something like fs.writeFile (? but I'm not sure if such alternative exist.

Comment: @andus - So, you can have multer put the file upload data in a temporary location on disk and then, after processing the whole form and deciding it is OK, you can then move the multer data where you want it to go.

Comment: Thanks for giving me lots of inspiration. I eventually figured out a way to do that and I would like to share with you, please check my answer :)